# Sequence of multiple left joins

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM test_youtube Y
LEFT JOIN test_youtubelike L ON youtubelike_videoId = youtube_videoId
LEFT JOIN test_youtubeview V ON youtubeview_videoId = youtube_videoId
GROUP BY Y.id
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 714 total, Query took 0.0062 sec)

SELECT * FROM test_youtube Y
LEFT JOIN test_youtubeview V ON youtubeview_videoId = youtube_videoId
LEFT JOIN test_youtubelike L ON youtubelike_videoId = youtube_videoId
GROUP BY Y.id
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 714 total, Query took 0.0169 sec)
```

The only difference in the above queries, is the sequence of left joins (L first, V latter versus V first L latter). I would think since both are independent left joins, it would not have mattered which left join is done first. However, the queries' speed differ vastly. Any insights please?

Comment: MySQL's optimizer often needs some help with rearranging queries to find the "correct" query plan. I suspect that is the case here. I don't think there are any more insights without the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: Unrelated but your group by usage is invalid (standard) SQL. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/